# Why are version numbers typically "2.1.3" instead of 2.13?

Tags: versioning

Why are version numbers typically "2.1.3" instead of 2.13?

Seems like the latter makes more sense, since you can run numerical comparators over it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... would 2.9 be newer/greater than 2.10?  what about 2.90?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reason that when the version number is encoded into an integer (e.g. Python's [sys.hexversion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.hexversion)), it's padded with zeroes:

You frequently have to go beyond 10.

Many projects adopt a *major.minor.bugfix* scheme (e.g. [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/)). Maybe version 2.1.9 has a security hole which need to patch; you'd need to call it 2.1.10 (because calling it 2.2.0 implies new features and possible minor incompatibilities). Maybe version 3 completely changes the syntax so you want to continue to add features to version 2.

Maybe your project simply releases so frequently that you have more than 100 minor/bugfix versions per major version (kernel.org lists 2.6.34.14 and 3.0.60).

Finally, it's a *string*. Sure, you can parse it into a double for comparison purposes, but plenty of languages/libraries support "numeric" string comparisons (so "Document 9" comes before "Document 10"); Apache's [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html) even calls it "VersionSort".

Answer (score 1):

The three level versioning scheme typically reflects major.minor.build (or major.minor.revision).

The three levels allow for decreasing significance of the changes between levels. The difference between software with major 1, minor 13 and major 1, minor 12 should be signficantly greater than the difference between major 1, minor 1, build 3 and major 1, minor 1, build 2.

You can split the version numbers on the . and compare each level individually.

Answer (score -2):

Even there is only one decimal point, you cannot use numerical comparator over it.

Here is the example.
Consider version 1.13 and 1.2, obviously 1.13 is the later version. But 1.2 > 1.13.

Comment: That depends on your convention; one is that the second component is always two digits, e.g. 1.00, 1.02, 1.13, 1.20.

Comment: But fixing the digit in second component also have another problem. For example, the version is weird if you do not usually have more than 10 sub builds. And how about this time you have more than 100 sub builds although it is not likely to happen.